# Exclude an entity result within a controller

Tags: php, symfony

This is my environment :

I have an entity :

```
Object
|____ id (integer)
|____ foo (string)
|____ configurations (collection)
```

The property `configurations` is a collection of `Configuration` entities mapped with a `oneToMany`. Anyway, that looks like this :

```
Configuration
|____ id (integer)
|____ bar (string)
|____ name (string, nullable)
```

I have a service to get a single `object` :

- This service is in a bundle which manage objects of many projects.
- This service is not aware of which project call it.
- This service is a set of filters, events listeners and sql queries. (something about 2K lines)
- Consider I **can't / don't want** to update its get process for what I want to do here.

I have the single action that I want to act on in my controller like this :

```
$objMgr = $this->get('objectManager'); //get my service I talked before
$object = $objMgr->findOneById(); //get my object

return array('object' => $object);// render template
```

I have lots of themes managing the end user screen with a twig file in each :

```
theme1
|____ object_details.html.twig
theme2
|____ object_details.html.twig
themeX
|____ object_details.html.twig
```

These `object_details.html.twig` have this code to print the configurations.

```
{% for config in object.configurations %}
    {# div config.blablabla etc. #}
{% endfor %}
```

## My question :

**According to the context above, can I exclude all configurations with a `name` property not null ?**

## Answer requirements :

- The answer **doesn't** edit the twig files (I know how to do that ^^)
- I want to be sure that the exclusion of a `configuration`, will not be detected by doctrine and it deletes this `config` of my database on a random flush somewhere in the code.
- The answer can be : "Dude, we can't do that". In fact, I'm very curious to know if it's possible. I have no idea at the moment.
- The answer must respect some best practices :)

Comments anticipation : *Why not edit twig files ?* : I have lots of themes, I want to know if it's possible to do it once.

*Why not exclude results in your db query ?* : Because I want these configurations in my other pages and projects using this getter.

+50 for the best try :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, but if you don't want a certain result, you can use `Except(...)`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i'm sorry, I think I missclicked on a tag proposed by Stack when I created the post. I'm actually working with Symfony2 and not entity-framework.

Comment: Do you want to remove it just from the results or also from the DB?

Comment: Only fron the results.

Comment: Have you tried to add a condition in your query in order to fetch this data?

Comment: You said you don't want to do it in your repo but this is probably the best solution. If you can write in your repo, maybe you could post the related method in there and we can help you to restrict properly your results if that's what bothers you.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to. I can't do it in my repo. In fact it is a complex serie of requests, events in an abstract bundle which manage many environments. But thank you for your comment

Comment: According to the code in the question, it's not *a complex serie of requests* because the *if* only checks a property for each child.

Comment: @A.L That's the point ! I have an `$object` retrieved by *a complex serie of requests* and I just need to exclude one or more configuration(s) in it. I'm not asking anyhting else.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/237701), you're explaining what you want but it may be not the best solution for your problem. How is this *complex serie of requests* written? Can't you reduce it to only one request? Can you please add the code from your repository in your question?

Comment: I totally refactored my question @A.L

Comment: Is this a *view-thing* only? So that code-wise you would still need to be able to get the full collection of configurations? But aside from that, have you thought about using a decorator object? E.g. create a new class which is configurable in regards to what configurations you want visible, and otherwise has the same api as `Object`. In your controller you could then do something like: `array('object' => new MyDecorator($object, %some config%));`

Comment: And to avoid `new` you could have a decorator factory service, which in turn can be configured through the service container. In effect, allowing someting like: `array('object' => $this->get('app.my_object_decorator_service')->decorate($object));`

Comment: Yes it is. I could try your solution associated with the bartlomiej's one. I'll come back to you. It will be fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*building on my comments above:*

One option, that would not reflect on anything but the view, would be to implement a (configurable) [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that exposes the same api as the original object.

This way the view, or maybe even other consumers wouldn't even know that they are dealing with a special case.

For example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Something;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class ObjectDecorator /* implement ObjectInterface // if needed */
{
    public function __construct(Object $object)
    {
        $this->base = $object;
    }

    public function getConfigurations()
    {
        //Using Criteria to make it cleaner than a loop.
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('name'));

        return $this->base->getConfigurations()->matching($criteria);
    }

    /*
    Override all your decorated entity getters with 
    public function getFoo() 
    {
        return $this->base->getFoo();
    }
    */
}
```

and in your controller use:

```
return array('object' => new ObjectDecorator($object));
```

---

You could extend this a number of ways:

- extract creation/configuration to a decorator-factory-service.
- create an interface that both objects (concrete and decorated) follow, so that they can savely be passed around.

Comment: I tried your solution with the criteria's one. It works really great for my configuration but I didn't found a way to hydrate my decorator object with the initial `Object` passed in constructor (to access the other properties without redefined all getters). I tried to extend my decorator with the `Object` entity. But only my `base` contains the value of each property.

Comment: @JulienBourdic That's right, using the decorator pattern implies that you need to add all public methods the decorated object has. This seems cumbersome, but really if your object doesn't change constantly this is a one-time-task. If this is still not acceptable, you could go and implement [magic methods](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to handle the delegation automatically (with exceptions for the decorated methods of course). This issn't inherently bad, but could be a performance problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You helped me well and I think it is the best way to do what I wanted to do. I've more than 100 getters in the `object` which is evolving. But you make me discovered something very cool. Thank you.

Comment: @JolienBourdic Lucky I could help! :)

Answer (score 4):

What you want is filtering by criteria:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

And an example:

```
// Entity class
class Department
{
    public function getEmployeesByEmployeeTypeId($employeeTypeId)
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('employeeType', $employeeTypeId));

        return $this->employees->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

in your case criteria would be like

```
$criteria->where("name is not null");      
return $this->configurations->matching($criteria);
```

Comment: This solution looks great and enjoying me, I'll test it asap and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks again for your time, It was useful and I added your solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand the whole problem, but I understand you want to get some items from a list in an entity and do not want to remove from the object for some reason. So, create a new function directly in the entity, in this function you can filter the list, and then return the new collection. In that way you do not compromises the object.

```
/**
 * Object
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Object
{
  /**
   * @var Collection
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Configuration", mappedBy="object")           
   */
   private $configurations
   //...
   public function getConfigurationsWithName()
    {
        $subResult = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->configurations as $configuration) {
          if ($configuration->getName() != null) {
              $subResult.add($configuration);
          } 
        }
        return $subResult;
    }
   //...
}
```

Then in twig

```
{% for filteredObject in object.configurationsWithName %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

So, the framework look for any getConfigurationsWithName inside the entity and find the new function. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, You have a pretty interesting and clean idea. But that is the same as I made in my twig. I have to modifiy all my twig files. I will edit my question.